# how to toggle daytick from angular-gantt

Tags: angularjs, gantt-chart

I'm using this library, [angular-gantt](https://www.angular-gantt.com/demo/) and I'm trying to tweak the view.

Since I would like to represent a wide timespan, I would like to remove the "watermark" that shows the day tick in order to remove this "noise" effect I get:

[image: watermark]

I'm not finding any option though. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the option you are looking for is the [view-scale](https://www.angular-gantt.com/configuration/attributes/#view-scale) attribute.  It is for setting how often the tick marks occur in the chart.